# Xamarin forms: Hide Flowlistview item including it's space from UI based on a string value

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, visibility

I am using `flowlistview` for listing images. I need to hide the image if `pageStatus` value is `OFF` and show the image if `pageStatus` value is `ON`. I tried like below:

**In model:**

```
public string pageStatus { get; set; }
public bool pictureStatus
        {
            get
            {
                if (pageStatus == "OFF")
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

**In XAML added `IsVisible="{Binding pictureStatus}"` for the image**. The images are not showing in the UI but blank spaces are showing for `OFF` status pictures like below.

[image]

**I need to remove that blank space also from the UI, how can I do that?**

Comment: You have 2 different questions in 1

Comment: @NickKovalsky I have only one question, how can I remove the white spaces?

Comment: You are binding to a property that doesn't fire anything when it changes. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your model and when you change the data bihind call OnPropertyChanged("pictureStatus") then it will be updated in your binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the source data before binding to your list view's items source. When you find its value is ON, add it to your final items source. I modify your code in your PhotoGalleryViewModel like:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var Response = await client.GetAsync("REST API");
if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string response = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    PhotoAlbum photoAlbum = new PhotoAlbum();
    List<PhotoList> dataList = new List<PhotoList>();
    if (response != "")
    {
        photoAlbum = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhotoAlbum>(response.ToString());
        foreach (var photos in photoAlbum.photoList)
        {
            if (!Items.Contains(photos))
            {
                Items.Add(photos);
            }

            // Instead of using primitive data, filter it here
            if (photos.pageStatus == "ON")
            {
                dataList.Add(photos);
            }
        }

        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<PhotoList>(dataList);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
    }
    else
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        if (Utility.IsIOSDevice())
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Something went wrong, please try again later.", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            ShowAlert("Something went wrong, please try again later.");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
    if (Utility.IsIOSDevice())
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Something went wrong at the server, please try again later.", "Ok");
    }
    else
    {
        ShowAlert("Something went wrong at the server, please try again later.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, either you remove the element completely from the ListView ItemsSource, or else, implement, in your viewmodel, the  INotifyProperty changed, to change the visibility of each element. Here is a small sample.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _pageStatus;
        private bool _pictureStatus;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string PageStatus
        {
            set
            {
                if (_pageStatus != value)
                {
                    _pageStatus = value;
                    if(_pageStatus.equals("OFF))
                    {
                        PictureStatus = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PictureStatus = true;
                    }
                    OnPropertyChanged("PageStatus");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _pageStatus;
            }
        }

        public bool PictureStatus
        {
            set
            {
                if (_pictureStatus != value)
                {
                    _pictureStatus = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PictureStatus");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _pictureStatus;
            }
        }



        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in XAML

```
IsVisible="{Binding PictureStatus}"
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions, the off status pictures are not showing in the list, but the blank spaces are still there.

Comment: Then, as I habve also said in my answer, you have to remove the element from the Collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IValueConverter easiliy:

XAML:

Define resource

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:ConverterNamespace" 

   <flowlistview.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
           <converter:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
      </ResourceDictionary>     
   </flowlistview.Resources>
```

Binding

```
IsVisible="{Binding pageStatus, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
```

Converter Class:

```
public class VisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {    
            if ((string)value == "ON" || (string)value != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;    
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }    
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

If you want to change property value later and to notify listview, you need to use INotifyPropertyChanged as above post.

In your model:

```
 public class ModelClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _pagestatus;
        public string pageStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return _pagestatus;
            }
            set
            {
                _pagestatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I tried your code, the off status pictures are not showing in the list, but still the blank space is there.

Comment: Instead of `<flowlistview.Resources>` I provide`<ContentPage.Resources>`

Comment: you can use the same converter for heightrequest

Comment: For which properties heightrequest? For the image? Our converter display only true or false value, then how it is possible to apply it for heightrequest?

Comment: HeightRequest="{Binding pageStatus, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"


Converter class:
switch (targetType.Name)
{
 case "Boolean":
  if ((string)value == "ON" || (string)value != null)
   return true;
  else
   return false;    

 case "Double":
  if ((string)value == "ON" || (string)value != null)
   return 30;
  else
   return 0;  
 default:
  return null;
}